# "Follow TCP stream" inserts extra line breaks and strings like "2000" "a7c" "0" (chunking?), how to hide that?

Tags: http, tcp, wireshark

I often use "Follow TCP stream", very convenient to see the whole client/server conversation.

**PROBLEM:** Some strange characters (that are not in the real packets) are shown. Maybe due to HTTP chunking?

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to hide them, and show the data like it is delivered after dechunking?

**EXAMPLE:** The following is supposed to be a single long line, but line breaks, and the words "2000" and "a7c", and a final "0", get inserted in "Follow TCP stream" (The QA system seems to eat the XML so please click "edit" to see the source):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Server: Apache-Chemistry-OpenCMIS/0.13.0
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; type=feed
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2016 06:50:20 GMT

2000
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><atom:feed xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/" xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"><atom:author><atom:name></atom:name></atom:author><atom:id>http://chemistry.apache.org/Y29udGVudENoYW5nZXM=</atom:id><atom:title>Content Change</atom:title><app:edited>2016-07-08T15:50:20.041+09:00</app:edited><atom:updated>2016-07-08T15:50:20.041+09:00</atom:updated><cmisra:numItems>5</cmisra:numItems><atom:link rel="service" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom?repositoryId=bedroom" type="application/atomsvc+xml" /><atom:link rel="self" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/changes?changeLogToken=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a8e8&amp;includeProperties=false&amp;includePolicyIds=false&amp;includeACL=false&amp;maxItems=5" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="next" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/changes?changeLogToken=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f874&amp;includeProperties=false&amp;includePolicyIds=false&amp;includeACL=false&amp;maxItems=5" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><chemistry:changeLogToken xmlns:chemistry="http://chemistry.apache.org/">3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f874</chemistry:changeLogToken><atom:entry><atom:author><atom:name>admin</atom:name></atom:author><atom:id>http://chemistry.apache.org/MzgwOGY1ZTQ4ZTk0ZTlkZjExMzFhNDJiMzgwMGE4MmE=</atom:id><atom:title>test.txt</atom:title><app:edited>2016-07-08T12:08:33.463+09:00</app:edited><atom:updated>2016-07-08T12:08:33.463+09:00</atom:updated><atom:content src="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/content/test.txt?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="text/plain" /><cmisra:object><cmis:properties><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId"><cmis:value>3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:baseTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name"><cmis:value>test.txt</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesId"><cmis:value>fb4640f91aedea7932321219fef9a60e</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionLabel"><cmis:value>1.6</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString></cmis:properties><cmis:changeEventInfo><cmis:changeType>created</cmis:changeType><cmis:changeTime>2016-07-08T03:08:33.746Z</cmis:changeTime></cmis:changeEventInfo></cmisra:object><atom:link rel="service" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom?repositoryId=bedroom" type="application/atomsvc+xml" /><atom:link rel="self" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" cmisra:id="3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" /><atom:link rel="enclosure" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="edit" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="describedby" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/type?id=cmis%3Adocument" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/allowableactions" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/allowableactions?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="application/cmisallowableactions+xml" /><atom:link rel="up" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/parents?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="version-history" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/versions?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a&amp;versionSeries=fb4640f91aedea7932321219fef9a60e" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="edit" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a&amp;returnVersion=latest" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="edit-media" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/content?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="text/plain" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/acl" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/acl?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="application/cmisacl+xml" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/policies" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/policies?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/relationships" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/relationships?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800a82a" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /></atom:entry><atom:entry><atom:author><atom:name>admin</atom:name></atom:author><atom:id>http://chemistry.apache.org/MzgwOGY1ZTQ4ZTk0ZTlkZjExMzFhNDJiMzgwMGJlOGY=</atom:id><atom:title>test.txt</atom:title><app:edited>2016-07-08T12:08:57.859+09:00</app:edited><atom:updated>2016-07-08T12:08:57.859+09:00</atom:updated><atom:content src="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/content/test.txt?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="text/plain" /><cmisra:object><cmis:properties><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId"><cmis:value>3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:baseTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name"><cmis:value>test.txt</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesId"><cmis:value>fb4640f91aedea7932321219fef9a60e</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionLabel"><cmis:value>1.7</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString></cmis:properties><cmis:changeEventInfo><cmis:changeType>created</cmis:changeType><cmis:changeTime>2016-07-08T03:08:58.151Z</cmis:changeTime></cmis:changeEventInfo></cmisra:object><atom:link rel="service" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom?repositoryId=bedroom" type="application/atomsvc+xml" /><atom:link rel="self" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" cmisra:id="3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" /><atom:link rel="enclosure" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="edit" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="describedby" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/type?id=cmis%3Adocument" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/allowableactions" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/allowableactions?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="application/cmisallowableactions+xml" /><atom:link rel="up" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/parents?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="version-history" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/versions?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f&amp;versionSeries=fb4640f91aedea7932321219fef9a60e" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="edit" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f&amp;returnVersion=latest" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="edit-media" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/content?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="text/plain" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/acl" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/acl?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="application/cmisacl+xml" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.o
2000
rg/ns/cmis/link/200908/policies" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/policies?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/relationships" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/relationships?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800be8f" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /></atom:entry><atom:entry><atom:author><atom:name>admin</atom:name></atom:author><atom:id>http://chemistry.apache.org/MzgwOGY1ZTQ4ZTk0ZTlkZjExMzFhNDJiMzgwMGQ4NGM=</atom:id><atom:title>test.txt</atom:title><app:edited>2016-07-08T12:41:46.577+09:00</app:edited><atom:updated>2016-07-08T12:41:46.577+09:00</atom:updated><atom:content src="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/content/test.txt?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="text/plain" /><cmisra:object><cmis:properties><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId"><cmis:value>3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:baseTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name"><cmis:value>test.txt</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesId"><cmis:value>fb4640f91aedea7932321219fef9a60e</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionLabel"><cmis:value>1.8</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString></cmis:properties><cmis:changeEventInfo><cmis:changeType>created</cmis:changeType><cmis:changeTime>2016-07-08T03:41:46.871Z</cmis:changeTime></cmis:changeEventInfo></cmisra:object><atom:link rel="service" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom?repositoryId=bedroom" type="application/atomsvc+xml" /><atom:link rel="self" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" cmisra:id="3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" /><atom:link rel="enclosure" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="edit" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="describedby" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/type?id=cmis%3Adocument" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/allowableactions" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/allowableactions?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="application/cmisallowableactions+xml" /><atom:link rel="up" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/parents?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="version-history" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/versions?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c&amp;versionSeries=fb4640f91aedea7932321219fef9a60e" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="edit" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c&amp;returnVersion=latest" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="edit-media" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/content?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="text/plain" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/acl" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/acl?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="application/cmisacl+xml" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/policies" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/policies?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/relationships" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/relationships?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800d84c" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /></atom:entry><atom:entry><atom:author><atom:name>admin</atom:name></atom:author><atom:id>http://chemistry.apache.org/MzgwOGY1ZTQ4ZTk0ZTlkZjExMzFhNDJiMzgwMGRkN2U=</atom:id><atom:title>test.txt</atom:title><app:edited>2016-07-08T12:42:03.583+09:00</app:edited><atom:updated>2016-07-08T12:42:03.583+09:00</atom:updated><atom:content src="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/content/test.txt?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="text/plain" /><cmisra:object><cmis:properties><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId"><cmis:value>3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:baseTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name"><cmis:value>test.txt</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesId"><cmis:value>fb4640f91aedea7932321219fef9a60e</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionLabel"><cmis:value>1.9</cmis:value></cmis:propertyString></cmis:properties><cmis:changeEventInfo><cmis:changeType>created</cmis:changeType><cmis:changeTime>2016-07-08T03:42:03.871Z</cmis:changeTime></cmis:changeEventInfo></cmisra:object><atom:link rel="service" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom?repositoryId=bedroom" type="application/atomsvc+xml" /><atom:link rel="self" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" cmisra:id="3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" /><atom:link rel="enclosure" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="edit" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="describedby" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/type?id=cmis%3Adocument" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/allowableactions" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/allowableactions?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="application/cmisallowableactions+xml" /><atom:link rel="up" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/parents?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="version-history" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/versions?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e&amp;versionSeries=fb4640f91aedea7932321219fef9a60e" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="edit-media" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/content?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="text/plain" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/acl" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/acl?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="application/cmisacl+xml" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/policies" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/policies?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/relationships" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/relationships?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800dd7e" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /></atom:entry><atom:entry><atom:author><atom:name>admin</atom:name></atom:author><atom:id>http://chemistry.apache.org/MzgwOGY1ZTQ4ZTk0ZTlkZjExMzFhNDJiMzgwMGYwYjk=</atom:id><atom:title>efwef</atom:title><app:edited>2016-07-08T12:43:02.834+09:00</app:edited><atom:updated>2016-07-08T12:43:02.834+09:00</atom:updated><cmisra:object><cmis:properties><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId"><cmis:value>3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:baseTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:folder</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId"><cmis:value>cmis:folder</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId><cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="
a7c
cmis:name"><cmis:value>efwef</cmis:value></cmis:propertyId></cmis:properties><cmis:changeEventInfo><cmis:changeType>created</cmis:changeType><cmis:changeTime>2016-07-08T03:43:02.877Z</cmis:changeTime></cmis:changeEventInfo></cmisra:object><atom:link rel="service" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom?repositoryId=bedroom" type="application/atomsvc+xml" /><atom:link rel="self" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" cmisra:id="3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" /><atom:link rel="enclosure" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="edit" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="describedby" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/type?id=cmis%3Afolder" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/allowableactions" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/allowableactions?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/cmisallowableactions+xml" /><atom:link rel="up" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/parent?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="down" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/children?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="down" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/descendants?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/cmistree+xml" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/foldertree" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/foldertree?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="edit" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/entry?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9&amp;returnVersion=latest" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/acl" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/acl?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/cmisacl+xml" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/policies" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/policies?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /><atom:link rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/relationships" href="http://52.69.35.160/core/atom/bedroom/relationships?id=3808f5e48e94e9df1131a42b3800f0b9" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" /></atom:entry></atom:feed>
0
```

Wireshark 2.0.2 on Ubuntu 2016.04

Answer (score 0):

> Some strange characters (that are not in the real packets) are shown. Maybe due to TCP chunking?

There is no TCP chunking. There is Transfer-Encoding chunked in the HTTP protocol (application layer not transport layer) and this is what you have here. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) for more details.

> Is there a way to hide them, and show the data like it is delivered after dechunking?

Since "Follow TCP stream" follows the TCP stream it will show all application data ransferred with TCP. Since HTTP chunking is at the application layer you will thus see it here and there is no way to get rid within "Follow TCP stream". But wireshark gives you a way to get to the unchunked (and even uncompressed) body - only not with "Follow TCP stream".